# Prove that every normed space of dimension 1 is a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

I was reading through my professor's notes and one of the exercises is to show that every one dimensional normed space is a Hilbert space. I'm not entirely sure how to define the inner product, but my first thought was to define it by $(x,y) = |xy|$. After this step, do I just show completion under the induced norm as usual? Or is there another a better way to approach this problem?

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Concerning $(x,y) = |xy|$, how do you define the product $xy$ on the right-hand side?

Comment: Any $1$-dimensional vector space $V$ is isomorphic to its ground field $\mathbb{k}$: choose a nonzero vector $v \in V$ and define $\eta: \mathbb{k} \to V$ sending $1 \mapsto v$.

Comment: @Filippo I guess I was thinking about it in the terms Sammy Black mentioned (the space being isomorphic to the ground field and so the product is just the usual multiplication), but I guess the definition doesn't make much sense on its own

Comment: @SammyBlack Thank you for the feedback. From this isomorphism are we immediately able to say that $V$ is a Hilbert space just because $\mathbb{K}$ is?

Comment: What you've said is true, and is the content of the claim that you intend to prove. Start with this map and transport structure from $\mathbb{k}$ over to $V$, and verify that everything works as expected. What is the form on $V$? Why is it bilinear? Symmetric? etc.

Comment: As the question is stated I think you need to prove that for any norm defined on $V$ there exists an inner product that induces this norm and then talk about completeness.

Comment: Try $(x,y) = \overline{x}y$, assuming that the field is real or complex.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, I think I have enough to work with now